# CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in AWS Amplify react app

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm trying to connect to an external API, specifically the api from TryTerra. My requests work fine locally, but when I upload it to Amplify, I encounter the error: 'has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.' I'm using GraphQL as my API in the application I'm developing.

I tried using custom headers in httpcustomheaders.yml

```
customHeaders:
  - pattern: '**/*'
    headers:
      - key: Access-Control-Allow-Origin
        value: '*'
```

but it hasn't worked either. I've seen that I can do it with Lambda or API Gateway services, but I don't know how.